# An argument named "azuread_authentication_only" is not expected here - Terraform Azure Synapse Workspace

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to implement [Synapse Workspace via Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_workspace) where AzureAD Only authentication is required.

This is my code:

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "synapse_workspace" {
  name                                 = var.workspace_name
  location                             = var.location
  resource_group_name                  = var.rg-name
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = var.filesystem_id
  sql_administrator_login              = var.synapse_sql_admin
  sql_administrator_login_password     = random_password.synapse-sql-password.result
  azuread_authentication_only = true 
  
  managed_virtual_network_enabled      = var.synapse_managed_vnet_enabled
  public_network_access_enabled        = var.synapse_public_access_enabled
  managed_resource_group_name          = var.managed_resource_group_name
}



│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on ../../modules/synapse_workspace/main.tf line 15, in resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "synapse_workspace":
│   15:   azuread_authentication_only = true 
│ 
│ An argument named "azuread_authentication_only" is not expected here.
```

As troubleshooting I have found out that I was using azurerm provider version v3.50.0 and I have changed that to 3.96.0.

Answer (score 0):

Found out in my pipeline output that it was still using version 3.50. I've changed all providers.tf versions from 3.50 to 3.96 and now it is working.